# List database values in a Combobox jsp with Bean Class Attached java

Tags: java, jsp, combobox

I am trying to list values from the database using JSP combobox like this:
My Vector Method:

```
 public Vector getCampusCode(StudentRegistrationBean srb){
        lgcampus = srb.getLgcampus();
        Vector v = new Vector();
        Connection conn = null;
        try{
          conn =  db.getDbConnection();
          Statement st = conn.createStatement();
          String sql = "select CAMPUS_CODE from campus_master where CAMPUS_NAME = '" + lgcampus + "'";
          ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
          while(rs.next()){
              String camp = rs.getString("CAMPUS_CODE");
              v.add(camp);
          }
        }catch(Exception asd){
            System.out.println(asd.getMessage());
        }
        return v;
    }
```

My JSP:

```
 <jsp:useBean id="obj1" class="com.kollega.dao.StudentRegistrationDao" scope="page"/>
 <jsp:useBean id="srb" class="com.kollega.bean.StudentRegistrationBean" scope="page"/>
 <option selected value="SELECT">SELECT</option>
                            <c:forEach var="item" items="${obj1.campusCode(srb)}">
                                <option>${item}</option>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </select>
```

Of course the Combo is not getting Populated and all the other components on the page after the Combo are masked(disappear). If I remove the bean attached to the Vector without the Where Condition, my values are getting listed. But i need only specific values and not all. how Can i achieve this?

Comment: are the both class="com.kollega.dao.StudentRegistrationDao" and com.kollega.bean.StudentRegistrationBean" have getter and setters method

Comment: No only the bean class has getter setter methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried to populate the values in the combo box, it worked just fine. Please see the code below -- JSP

```
<jsp:useBean id="obj1" class="com.tutorial.ComboValues" scope="page"> </jsp:useBean>
<jsp:useBean id="obj2" class="com.tutorial.Input" scope="page"> </jsp:useBean>
<select>
<option selected value="SELECT">SELECT</option>
                            <c:forEach var="item" items="${obj1.getValues(obj2)}">
                                <option>${item}</option>
                            </c:forEach>
 </select>
```

---

**ComboValues class**

```
public class ComboValues {
    public Vector getValues(Input i){
        Vector v = new Vector<String>();
        if(i.getInput()==0)
            v.add("worked");
        else
           v.add("it hurts");
        return v;
    }
}
```

---

**Input class**

```
public class Input {

    int value = 0;

    public void setInput(int i){
        this.value = i;
    }

    public int getInput(){
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

---

The problem may be in the reference 'srb' you are passing to `StudentRegistrationDao#getCampusCode` since `jsp:useBean` will create a new instance of that type when there is no such object available. The other area to check is  `lgcampus = srb.getLgcampus();` whether it returns a proper value for the where clause. Hope this helps

Comment: Please accept my answer, if it was helpful to you. Please let you know that i have taken sometime for you to help your problem.